# Flutter, how to call a function inside Stateful Widget from a returned Widget?

Tags: flutter

I would like to break down my Scaffold into smaller pieces for easy read.  I separate widgets into functions and return to the scaffold tree.  But I don't know how to make use of the function declared inside the stateful widget which need to setState the UI.

Part of my code:

```
Future<List<dataRecord>>? dataList;

class _clientDetailState extends State<clientDetail> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  List<dataRecord> parseJson(String responseBody) {
    final parsed =
        convert.jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<dataRecord>((json) => dataRecord.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  Future<List<dataRecord>> fetchData(http.Client client) async {
    final response = await client
        .get(Uri.parse('test.php'));
    return parseJson(response.body);
  }

  Body: myButton,
        ListView,
```

```
Widget myButton() {
  return TextButton(
    child: Text('test'),
    onTap: () {
      dataList = fetchData(http.Client());   //Method not found
    },
}
```

Comment: Use method instead of function so you can use all variables and setState in that method

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple way to do

```
class ClientDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  const ClientDetail({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ClientDetail> createState() => _ClientDetailState();
}

class _ClientDetailState extends State<ClientDetail> {

  List<dataRecord> dataList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
  children: [
      myButton(),
      ...dataList.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
     ],
    );
  }

  List<dataRecord> parseJson(String responseBody) {
    final parsed =
        convert.jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<dataRecord>((json) => dataRecord.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  Future<List<dataRecord>> fetchData(http.Client client) async {
    final response = await client.get(Uri.parse('test.php'));
    return parseJson(response.body);
  }

  Widget myButton() {
    return TextButton(
        child: const Text('test'),
        onPressed: () async {
          setState(() async {
            dataList = await fetchData(http.Client());
          });
        });
  }
}
```

**Tip**: always start class name with capital letter, e.g. **ClientDetail** instead of **clienDetail** also **DataRecord** instead of **dataRecord**

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your actual function as a parameter to the widget's function and then call it directly from state;

```dart
Body: myButton(onPressed: () => fetchData(http.Client())),
ListView,

Widget myButton({required void Function()? onPressed}) {
  return TextButton(
    child: Text('test'),
    onPressed: onPressed,
  );
}
```

Comment: What about if it is not a button but a card like:

                            return ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: dl.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return dataCard(context, dl, index);

and the onTap aciton in dataCard?

Comment: There is no difference